# HTTP Status 500 - Font 'Arial' is not available to the JVM

Tags: linux, tomcat, jasper-reports

I have made my report on *iReport*, in localhost it runs normally 'cause i got OS Microsoft , but when i run my project in Linux Server, the report show me an error

```
HTTP Status 500 - Font 'Arial' is not available to the JVM. See the Javadoc for more details.

net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRFontNotFoundException: Font 'Arial' is not available to the JVM. See the Javadoc for more details.
```

I guess I have to install the Font in my Linux Server, but I got this server for Free on Jelastic, someone can help me Please 'cause i have to run this on my Linux Server rented.

Comment: Check whether you arial.ttf is install on your server or not. If not install it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fonts are protected by copyright. If you don't have a license from the font owner to install it somewhere, it's better to try to use the fonts available on your target system.

Comment: Thank you, I solve it using fonts of my instace, I didn't know where are there but I found it and changed it.